# Win10 Mobile Hotspot from settings vs. Hotspot via netsh wlan start hostednetwork

Tags: windows-10, networking, hotspot

Windows 10 contains two way to start a hotspot:

1. "Mobile Hotspot" that you can enable to Internet connection sharing
2. "hostednetwork" Wifi hotspot you can configure and enable via command line (e.g. `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`)

Even if both hotspots seem to to the same they are a bit different, especially looking at the requirements:

The "Mobile Hotspot" seem to work with (nearly) any Wifi hardware, where the hostednetwork hotspot requires special hardware support which is not present in most Wifi adapters.

On the other hand it seems like you can not use "Mobile Hotspot" without data routing (sharing the network connection).

Does Windows 10 really have to independent implementations of the same functionality and why is hostednetwork hotspot limited to special hardware if the "Mobile Hotspot" demonstrates that any hardware is sufficient to run a hotspot...

Comment: It's all down to the drivers, really. There are (almost) no hardware restrictions regarding this.